# Horizontal Layout in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-grid, jquery-mobile-select

I'm working on a jquery mobile app. In my app, I have some form data that i want to layout horizontally. Currently, I have the following:

```
<div data-role="content">        
  <ul data-role="listview"> 
    <li data-role="list-divider">Information Here</li>
  </ul><br />

  <ul id="myList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-dividertheme="d">
    <li data-role="list-divider">Choice</li>
    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
      <div class="ui-grid-c">
        <div class="ui-block-a" style="font-weight:normal;">From</div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
          <select name="selector1" id="selector"1 data-native-menu="false">
            <option value="__">Please Choose</option>                
          </select>                    
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-c" style="font-weight:normal;">To</div>                
        <div class="ui-block-d">
          <select name="selector2" id="selector2" data-native-menu="false">
            <option value="__">Please Choose</option>                
          </select>                    
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My challenge is, the grid approach evenly divides the the 4 columns. In reality, I just want to lay the elements out horizontally. I don't need everything to be evenly spaced. However, I'm not sure how to do this.

How do I just layout content horizontally?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/K9duV/

```
<ul id="myList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-dividertheme="d">
<li data-role="list-divider">Choice</li>
<li>
  <div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a" style="font-weight:normal;">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="left-select">
            <label for="selector1">From:</label>            
            <select name="selector1" id="selector1" data-native-menu="false">
                <option value="__">Please Choose</option>                
            </select>
        </div>   
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="right-select">
            <label for="selector2">To:</label>               
            <select name="selector2" id="selector2" data-native-menu="false">
                <option value="__">Please Choose</option>                
            </select>                                
        <div>    
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Doesn't this evenly divide everything across two columns though? Essentially, I want one single column where everything is horizontally layed-out.

Comment: So close! I keep playing with it, but there's one minor problem. If one of the labels is larger, Image "From:" being something like "Begin From:" the text wraps. In addition, the select drop downs "Please Choose" text is cut off. I added "white-space:nowrap". That helped. But, it didn't solve the fact that the text gets cut off. ANy ideas? Thank you so much for your help.